# Working with multiple @ControllerAdvice classes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

I recently start to work with a `@ControllerAdvice` class to manage the exceptions in my Spring project. My current implementation is something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null) throw e;
        return new ModelAndView("error/5xx", "exception", e);
    }

}
```

My next step should be handle more exceptions, but for this I am thinking of use multiple classes with `@ControllerAdvice`, one for http status code. My goal is make the methods of my controller which handle the form submissions redirect the user for some of my custom status pages (I have one for each group - 1xx, 2xx, 3xx, 4xx, 5xx).

That methods have a structure similar to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
public String cadastra(Model model) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    model.addAttribute("command", this.entity.newInstance());
    return "private/cadastrar";
}
```

Anyone can tell me if this is a good approach and give some hint of how implement my controller methods to accomplish what I want?

Comment: have a look [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to define specific exception classes (thrown by your controller, for example: NoResourceFoundException or InvalidResourceStatusException and so on) so your ExceptionController can seperate the different cases and redirect them to the proper status page.

Answer (score 8):

You can have multiple `@ControllerAdvice` classes that handle different exceptions.

However, because you are handling the `Exception.class` on your `GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler`, any exception might be swallowed by it.

The way I got around this was to add `@Order( value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE )`
 on my general exception handler and `@Order( value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE )` on the others.

Comment: Thank you, it was the problem on an existing project, created an Advice was not catching my exception and I figured out there was a global own bind in the Throwable class...

Comment: Good to hear @Vincent, take care!

Comment: Awesome, finally was able to solve a bug after 1 month.